# How to implement camera movement within noise generated terrain

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, perlin-noise

I am trying to convert this Java's sketch:
https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/144860
into JavaScript program.
Here is my online version of it, with whole code:
https://editor.p5js.org/drunkenjanna/sketches/ZUbU7t632
Everything works as intended, as long as the sketch is static, without camera movement.
For people, who doesn't know p5 and processing, setup() is called once at the start of the program, and draw() is called every frame. There are also some functions like noise() and constrain(), but they shouldn't be a problem. I think the solution is somewhere in offsets, but I might be totally wrong.

```js
let noiseScale = 0.003;
let useMouse = false;

let gradientMap;
let cloudMap;

let clouds = [];
let ground = [];

let invertNoise = false;
let showDebug = false;
let cloudsOn = false;

let lastTime = 0;
let Speed = 1000;
let CloudSpeed = Speed * 1.5;

// Let the user move around to make things more interesting
let camPos = new p5.Vector(0, 0);
let camVel = new p5.Vector(0, 0);

let cloudCamPos = new p5.Vector(0, 0);
let cloudCamVel = new p5.Vector(0, 0);

let hasSetup = false;


function keyPressed() {
    // I key for toggling inversion
    if (keyCode == 73) {
        invertNoise = !invertNoise;
        generateGround();
        generateClouds();
    }
    // C key for toggling clouds
    else if (keyCode == 67) {
        cloudsOn = !cloudsOn;
        generateClouds();
    } else if (keyCode == 68) {
        showDebug = !showDebug;
    }
}

function preload() {
    // Create/Load gradient maps
    gradientMap = loadImage('a.png');
}

function setup() {

    createCanvas(500, 500);
    noSmooth();

    lastTime = millis();


    gradientMap.loadPixels()
    cloudMap = createImage(255, 1);
    cloudMap.loadPixels();
    for (let i = 0; i < cloudMap.width; i++) {
        cloudMap.set(i, 0, color(255, i))
    }

    cloudMap.updatePixels();

    ground[0] = createImage(width, height);
    ground[1] = createImage(width, height);

    clouds[0] = createImage(width, height);
    clouds[1] = createImage(width, height);

    ground[0].loadPixels();
    ground[1].loadPixels();

    clouds[0].loadPixels();
    clouds[1].loadPixels();
}

/*
 *
 */
function imageSubCopy(src, dst, xOffset, yOffset) {
    let dstX = 0;
    let dstY = 0;

    let srcX = 0;
    let srcY = 0;

    if (xOffset < 0) {
        srcX = abs(xOffset);
    } else {
        dstX = xOffset; //1
    }

    if (yOffset < 0) {
        srcY = abs(yOffset);
    } else {
        dstY = yOffset;
        srcY = 0;
    }

    for (; dstX < src.width && srcX < src.width; dstX++, srcX++) {
        for (; dstY < src.height && srcY < src.height; dstY++, srcY++) {
            index1 = 4 * (dstX + (dstY * src.width))
            index2 = 4 * (srcX + (srcY * src.width))
            dst.pixels[index1] = dst.pixels[index2]
            dst.pixels[index1 + 1] = dst.pixels[index2 + 1]
            dst.pixels[index1 + 2] = dst.pixels[index2 + 2]
            dst.pixels[index1 + 3] = dst.pixels[index2 + 3]
        }

        if (yOffset < 0) {
            srcY = abs(yOffset);
            dstY = 0;
        } else {
            dstY = abs(yOffset);
            srcY = 0;
        }
    }

}

function generateNoiseX(img, startXOffset, xWidth, shiftX, shiftY, map) {

    for (let x = startXOffset; x < startXOffset + xWidth; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            let n = noise((x - shiftX) * noiseScale, (y - shiftY) * noiseScale);
            n = invertNoise ? 1 - n : n;
            index1 = 4 * (y * img.width + x)
            index2 = 4 * (int(n * (map.width - 1)))
            img.pixels[index1] = map.pixels[index2]
            img.pixels[index1 + 1] = map.pixels[index2 + 1]
            img.pixels[index1 + 2] = map.pixels[index2 + 2]
            img.pixels[index1 + 3] = map.pixels[index2 + 3]
        }
    }

}

function generateNoiseY(img, startYOffset, xHeight, shiftX, shiftY, map) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (let y = startYOffset; y < xHeight + startYOffset; y++) {
            let n = noise((x - shiftX) * noiseScale, (y - shiftY) * noiseScale);
            n = invertNoise ? 1 - n : n;
            index1 = 4 * (y * img.width + x)
            index2 = 4 * (int(n * (map.width - 1)))
            img.pixels[index1] = map.pixels[index2]
            img.pixels[index1 + 1] = map.pixels[index2 + 1]
            img.pixels[index1 + 2] = map.pixels[index2 + 2]
            img.pixels[index1 + 3] = map.pixels[index2 + 3]
        }
    }

}

function generateClouds() {
    noiseDetail(20, 0.5);
    generateNoiseX(clouds[0], 0, width, int(cloudCamPos.x), int(cloudCamPos.y), cloudMap);
    image(clouds[0], 0, 0);
}

function generateGround() {
    noiseDetail(20, 0.5);
    generateNoiseX(ground[0], 0, width, int(camPos.x), int(camPos.y), gradientMap);
    image(ground[0], 0, 0);
}

function draw() {
    if (hasSetup == false) {
        if (gradientMap.width > 0) {
            generateGround();
            generateClouds();
            hasSetup = true;
        }
        return;
    }
    let t = millis();

    let dt = (millis() - lastTime) / 1000.0;
    dt = constrain(dt, 0, 0.3);


    camVel.x = int(map(mouseX, 0, width, Speed, -Speed) * dt);
    camVel.y = int(map(mouseY, 0, height, Speed, -Speed) * dt );

    camPos.add(camVel);
     
    cloudCamVel.x = int(map(mouseX, 0, width, CloudSpeed, -CloudSpeed) * dt);
    cloudCamVel.y = int(map(mouseY, 0, height, CloudSpeed, -CloudSpeed) * dt);
    cloudCamPos.add(cloudCamVel);


    if (cloudsOn) {
        imageSubCopy(clouds[0], clouds[1], int(cloudCamVel.x), int(cloudCamVel.y));
    }

    // Move the image over, add noise to the 'missing' part
    imageSubCopy(ground[0], ground[1], int(camVel.x), int(camVel.y));


    if (!cloudsOn) {
        noiseDetail(20, 0.5);
    }

    let xStartOffset = camVel.x > 0 ? 0 : width - int(abs(camVel.x));
    let yStartOffset = camVel.y > 0 ? 0 : height - int(abs(camVel.y));

    generateNoiseX(ground[1], xStartOffset, int(abs(camVel.x)), int(camPos.x), int(camPos.y), gradientMap);
    generateNoiseY(ground[1], yStartOffset, int(abs(camVel.y)), int(camPos.x), int(camPos.y), gradientMap);

    ground[0].updatePixels();
    ground[1].updatePixels();

    image(ground[1], 0, 0);
    swap(ground);

    let diff = millis() - t;
    lastTime = millis();

    if (showDebug) {
        fill(0);
        text(diff + " ms", 40, 40);
        text(int(frameRate()) + " FPS", 40, 60);
    }
}

function getOffset(shift, maxSize) {
    return shift > 0 ? 0 : maxSize - abs(shift);
}

function swap(pArray) {
    let temp = pArray[0];
    pArray[0] = pArray[1];
    pArray[1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: If you check the first link, there would be a possibility to move camera around with mouse. And in my sketch, once I move camera, everything goes totally crazy